# Blank cells while reading substring and numbers from with a string with textscan

Tags: matlab, textscan, file-import

I have a text file that consists of line after line of data in an xml-like format like this:

```
<item type="newpoint1" orient_zx="0.8658983248810842" orient_zy="0.4371062806139187" orient_zz="0.2432245678709263" electrostatic_force_x="0" electrostatic_force_y="0" electrostatic_force_z="0" cust_attr_HMTorque_0="0" cust_attr_HMTorque_1="0" cust_attr_HMTorque_2="0" vel_x="0" vel_y="0" vel_z="0" orient_xx="-0.2638371745169712" orient_xy="-0.01401379799313232" orient_xz="0.9644654264455047" pos_x="0" cust_attr_BondForce_0="0" pos_y="0" cust_attr_BondForce_1="0" pos_z="0.16" angvel_x="0" cust_attr_BondForce_2="0" angvel_y="0" id="1" angvel_z="0" charge="0" scaling_factor="1" cust_attr_BondTorque_0="0" cust_attr_BondTorque_1="0" cust_attr_BondTorque_2="0" cust_attr_Damage_0="0" orient_yx="0.4249823952954215" cust_attr_HMForce_0="0" cust_attr_Damage_1="0" orient_yy="-0.8993006799250595" cust_attr_HMForce_1="0" orient_yz="0.1031903618333235" cust_attr_HMForce_2="0" />
```

I'm only interested in the values within the " " so I'm trying to read this with textscan. To do this I take the first line and do regex find/replace to swap all number for %f and strings for %s, like this:

```
expression = '"[-+]?\d*\.?\d*"';
expression2 = '"\w*?"';

newStr = regexprep(firstline,expression,'"%f"');
FormatString = sprintf('%s',regexprep(newStr,expression2,'"%s"'));
```

The I re-open the file to read the files with string with the following call:

```
while ~feof(InputFile) % Read all lines in file    
    data = textscan(InputFile,FormatString,'delimiter','\n');    
end
```

But all i get is an array of empty cells. I can't see what my mistake is - can someone point me in the right direction?

#### Clarification:

Mathworks provides this following example for textscan to remove literal text, which is what I'm trying to do.

*"Remove the literal text 'Level' from each field in the second column of the data from the previous example."*

```
filename = fullfile(matlabroot,'examples','matlab','scan1.dat');
fileID = fopen(filename);
C = textscan(fileID,'%s Level%d %f32 %d8 %u %f %f %s %f');
fclose(fileID);
C{2}
```

Comment: `regexp(text, '"(.*?)"', 'match')`   ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍? ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍

Comment: That doesn't tell me why my format string isn't working for textscan. Granted it is another possible approach though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after looking at this with some fresh eyes today I spotted my problem.

```
newStr = regexprep(firstline,expression,'"%f"');
FormatString = sprintf('%s',regexprep(newStr,expression2,'%q'));

data = textscan(InputFile,FormatString,'delimiter',' ');
```

The replacement of the string need to be switched to the *%q* option which allows a string within double quotes to be read and the delimiter for textscan needed to be reverted to a single space. Code working fine now.